# Compiling sqilte3 on Mac

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to Compile sqlite3 to Set Size Limits, yet the official site https://www.sqlite.org/howtocompile.html only provide solutions for windows, is there a step-by-step recipe for compiling on Mac?

Comment: Are you wanting to build it as a library, or just including the source in your own C or C++ project?

Comment: i am trying to build a library similar to the original, only changing the limits

Comment: That's easy. Assuming you're not wanting to define any options that require rebuilding the amalgamation, just download the autoconf version of the source, and add in the step of editing the makefile to add the defines you need between running configure and make (Or just specify them in `CFLAGS` when running configure; there are examples in the readme)

Comment: should i edit the Makefile.msc file or Makefile.in file?